# How to convert a Flat list merge to a hierarchy string

Tags: c++

I have a map from string to string, for example, the map have 4 entries, the keys are: a.b.c, a.b.d, a.b, a.e and the values are 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively.

```
std::map<string, string> myMap;
myMap["a.b.c"] = "1";
myMap["a.b.d"] = "2";
myMap["a.b"] = "3";
myMap["a.e"] = "4";
```

Now I would like to build a string in a hierarchy format:

```
string myFunc(const std::map<string, string>& m)
{
    //the implementation?
}
```

Then I test with:

```
string myString = myFunc(myMap);
```

myString could be like:

```
a(b(c=1, d=2), b=3, e=4)
```

Note: the order of the comma separated items are not important.

Comment: And what exactly have you tried to do, already, in order to implement your desired algorithm?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, well, just some brain storm.... I've implemented in an object oriented way (see my own post) rather than stuck on a single function. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Rather than got stuck on the ideal function, I implemented in a different way:

```
class TreeItem
{
public:
    string name;
    string value;
    TreeItem* parent;
    std::vector<TreeItem*> children;
};
```

Then do a tokenize on the flat keys to create chained TreeItems; the result is a tree whose root is a, with two childrens, b and e, and b further have two children c and d.

Then a Depth First Search on the tree printed my expected result.